# python regex positive look behind with optional character

Tags: python, regex, positive-lookbehind

I am trying to come up with a regex that captures the word `zone` in both scenarios below:

```
txt1='cast("zone" as varchar(100)) as zoneID'
txt2='cast(zone as varchar(100)) as zoneID'
```

As you can see, the `"` is optional. sometimes it appears and sometimes it doesn't. so the regex needs to work in both scenarios.

I have tried the following:

```
(?<=cast\()"?zone(?=\s|")
```

but the output is

```
"zone
```

when I incorporate the optional quote `"?` inside of the positive look behind I get the following message:

```
(?<=cast\("?)zone(?=\s|")
look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

I think the parenthesis is causing the issue. How can I incorporate the optional quote in the positive look-behind?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to replace zone with something else? Do you just need the index of zone? Why are you using a positive look ahead instead of a look behind?

Comment: `r'((zone)|("zone"))'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using a positive look behind to begin with. You could locate zone by simply doing this:

```
import re

txt1='cast("zone" as varchar(100)) as zoneID'
txt2='cast(zone as varchar(100)) as zoneID'

dasearch=re.search("\(\"?(zone)\"?",txt1)

print(dasearch.group(1))

dasearch=re.search("\(\"?(zone)\"?",txt2)

print(dasearch.group(1))
```

With more info on why you need a positive look ahead, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: good point. I was thinking that if instead of using zoneid as the alias one uses zone, then it might capture both, but I only want the zone inside of the cast, which starts with `cast(`

Answer (score 0):

In Python you could make use of an if clause and get the value from capture group 2.

```
\bcast\((")?(zone)(?(1)"|\s)
```

**Explanation**

- `\bcast\(` Match `cast(`
- `(")?` Optionally match `"` in group 1
- `(zone)` Capture `zone` in group 2
- `(?(1)"|\s)` If clause, if we have group 1, then match `"` else match a whitespace char

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sMu247/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NNbF7W).

```
import re

pattern = r'\bcast\((")?(zone)(?(1)"|\s)'
strings = [
    'cast("zone" as varchar(100)) as zoneID',
    'cast(zone as varchar(100)) as zoneID',
    'cast(zone) as varchar(100)) as zoneID'
]
for s in strings:
    m = re.search(pattern, s)
    if m:
        print(f"{m.group(2)} ---> {s}")
```

Output

```
zone ---> cast("zone" as varchar(100)) as zoneID
zone ---> cast(zone as varchar(100)) as zoneID
```